# BrowserConfigurationAuthError

Tags: angular, msal-angular

Though I have updated store auth cookies to true sill I am getting this issue,Here is my code

```
{
    "clientID": "Account GUID",
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/36da45f1-dd2c-4d1f-af13-5abe46b99921",
    "redirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "cacheLocation": "localStorage",
    "storeAuthStateInCookie": true,
    "protectedResourceMap": [
        ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]]
    ],
    "protectedResourceMap": [],
    "eSign_scopes": "https://devapi.esignatureglobal.deloitte.com/user_impersonation"
   
   }
```

Cleared Cookies but still the issues persists
The Issue:BrowserConfigurationAuthError:

> in_mem_redirect_unavailable: Redirect cannot be supported. In-memory storage was selected and storeAuthStateInCookie=false, which would cause the library to be unable to handle the incoming hash. If you would like to use the redirect API, please use session/localStorage or set storeAuthStateInCookie=true.